# Why does my sqlcmd .bat fail through due to login on Jenkins but not when run manually?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, jenkins, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

I have a .bat file that runs sqlcmd and runs a .sql script. When I run it manually through the user the Jenkins Service runs under everything works fine. But when Jenkins runs the job to execute the same .bat file I get a login failed.

I am running the .bat through Jenkins like this:

```
C:\MasterFiles\ListingsManagement\LH.bat > batResults.txt
```

The .bat looks like this:

```
 sqlcmd -S <Server> -E -i C:\MasterFiles\ListingsManagement\test.sql 
 -o C:\MasterFiles\ListingsManagement\results.txt
```

and when run through Jenkins the error message is:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Login failed for user '<domain>\svc_jenkins'..
```

Server name and Domain name have purposefully been removed.

Sql is 2014 Enterprise, and Jenkins is at 1.645 and all this is running on a Windows 7 vm.

Comment: When you "run it manually" are you doing so on the SQL cluster? Presumably when run through Jenkins it is run from another machine.

Comment: Instead of using -E(trusted connection) can you try providing username and password and run it through Jenkins. I think your credentials are not matching.  **sqlcmd -S <Server> -U username -P password -i C:\MasterFiles\ListingsManagement\test.sql**

Comment: -U -P does not work with domain credentials and our DBA's wont add a local user. I did restart the Jenkins service and it started working. It doesnt make sense... Stupid technology :)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command manually, are you certain you are logged in as `<domain>\svc_jenkins` on the same machine Jenkins runs on?

Can you confirm the contents of the environment variables **USERDOMAIN** and **USERNAME** match `<domain>\svc_jenkins?` when you are logged in manually and run the script?

One of those tests should flag a problem.

Comment: This showed the proper domain and username, after I did this I restarted Jenkins and it started working.